# KQL (Kusto) to show a Graph that contains total Snapshot count over a period of time

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-resource-graph

I have been looking for a Kusto query that will form a graph to show the total count of snapshots over time.

Time period by 1 week gap.

## Tried the below queries, but did not work. Please help. Thanks, in adv.

```
Snapshots
| summarize TotalSnapshots=count() by bin(Timestamp, 1w)
| render timechart
```

======================================================

```
resources
| where type == "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots"
| extend CreationDate = todatetime(properties.CreationDate)
| summarize count() by bin(CreationDate, 7d)
| render timechart
```

=====================================================

Comment: What is the issue with above queries? @user23419269

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using [render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/render-operator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#syntax) operator will be used to display KQL results as a graph or bar or any other visualization.

Your code looks good to me. Alternatively, you can also use below query to achieve the requirement.

```
Snapshots
| summarize total = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d)
| extend week = startofweek(TimeGenerated)
| project total,week
| render timechart
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Jahnavi,

I tried your Query. Getting following error. Any idea?

==================================

Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2024-03-04T03:37:55.0965638Z, correlationId = c0cfebf2-8bb2-4b23-94d8-d1cfe97b6ed1. (Code:BadRequest)

Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)

Comment: It worked for me with no errors. Are you trying to execute the same query as provided by me? @user23419269

Comment: Yes. I copied the entire code from you.

Comment: Check if any extra commas or operators added while copying the code. @user23419269